# Url.RouteUrl in the callback of an ajax and add params using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in the callback of an ajax call:

```
jQuery.each(res, function () 
{
   var anchor = $("<a/>", { id: this.UrlTitle, text: this.Name.toLowerCase(), style: 'color:#000000;' });
    anchor.attr('href', @(Url.RouteUrl("Detail",new{indicator=this.Name,urltitle=this.NameUrl}));");
});
```

I would like to use this.Name and this.UrlTitle inside of the foreach.

The problem is that i want to avoid to use querystrings variables (?param=1, etc...)

Do you know how to inject jquery variables into the html helper Url.RouteUrl?

Thanks in advance

regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.each(res, function () {
    var anchor = $('<a/>', { 
        id: this.UrlTitle, 
        text: this.Name.toLowerCase(), 
        style: 'color:#000000;' 
    });
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("Detail", new { indicator = "__indicator__", urltitle = "__title__" })'
        .replace('__indicator__', encodeURIComponent(this.Name))
        .replace('__title__', encodeURIComponent(this.NameUrl));
    anchor.attr('href', url);
});
```